# Add action to all blog pages

Tags: wordpress, function, storefront

I'd like to have a specific header for all my blog pages (Home / Single Post / Archive (tags, author, categories, etc).

I've managed to target the homepage of the blog but not the rest (single / archives) :

```
function add_blog_header_single() {
// Echo out content
if ( is_home() && !is_front_page() ) {
    echo
    '<div id="blog-header"><p>
     <img src="img.png" alt="">
     </p></div>'
     ;
     }
}
add_action( 'storefront_content_top' , 'add_blog_header_single', 20 );
```

What should I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, add this code in your theme functions.php file.

```
function add_blog_header_single() {
 $img_src = 'default-image.png'
 if ( is_home() ) { // When the main blog page is being displayed.
  $img_src = 'blog.png';
 }
 if( is_single() ) { // When a single post of any post type (except attachment and page post types) is being displayed.
  $img_src = 'single-post.png';
 }
 if( is_archive() ) { // When any type of Archive page is being displayed. Category, Tag, other Taxonomy Term, custom post type archive, Author and Date-based pages are all types of Archives.
  $img_src = 'archive.png';
 }   
 echo '<div id="blog-header"><p> <img src="'.$img_src.'" alt=""></p></div>';
}
add_action( 'storefront_content_top' , 'add_blog_header_single', 20 );
```